# AttributeError: 'Seq2SeqTrainingArguments' object has no attribute 'generation_config'

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers

hello everyone I want to use Seq2SeqTrainingArguments for training an EncoderDecoder model But I keep getting this error :

> AttributeError: 'Seq2SeqTrainingArguments' object has no attribute 'generation_config'

My code is here :

a few imports

```
!pip install sacrebleu==1.4.12
!pip install rouge_score
from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainer

#from seq2seq_trainer import Seq2SeqTrainer
from transformers import TrainingArguments
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional
```

and data class:

```
@dataclass
class Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(TrainingArguments):
    label_smoothing: Optional[float] = field(
        default=0.0, metadata={"help": "The label smoothing epsilon to apply (if not zero)."}
    )
    sortish_sampler: bool = field(default=False, metadata={"help": "Whether to SortishSamler or not."})
    predict_with_generate: bool = field(
        default=False, metadata={"help": "Whether to use generate to calculate generative metrics (ROUGE, BLEU)."}
    )
    adafactor: bool = field(default=False, metadata={"help": "whether to use adafactor"})
    encoder_layerdrop: Optional[float] = field(
        default=None, metadata={"help": "Encoder layer dropout probability. Goes into model.config."}
    )
    decoder_layerdrop: Optional[float] = field(
        default=None, metadata={"help": "Decoder layer dropout probability. Goes into model.config."}
    )
    dropout: Optional[float] = field(default=None, metadata={"help": "Dropout probability. Goes into model.config."})
    attention_dropout: Optional[float] = field(
        default=None, metadata={"help": "Attention dropout probability. Goes into model.config."}
    )
    lr_scheduler: Optional[str] = field(
        default="linear", metadata={"help": f"Which lr scheduler to use."}
    )
```

and here is functions for evaluation

```
# load rouge for validation
rouge = datasets.load_metric("rouge")

def compute_metrics(pred):
    labels_ids = pred.label_ids
    pred_ids = pred.predictions

    # all unnecessary tokens are removed
    pred_str = tokenizer.batch_decode(pred_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)
    labels_ids[labels_ids == -100] = tokenizer.pad_token_id
    label_str = tokenizer.batch_decode(labels_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)

    rouge_output = rouge.compute(predictions=pred_str, references=label_str, rouge_types=["rouge2"])["rouge2"].mid

    return {
        "rouge2_precision": round(rouge_output.precision, 4),
        "rouge2_recall": round(rouge_output.recall, 4),
        "rouge2_fmeasure": round(rouge_output.fmeasure, 4),
    }
```

FINALLY THIS IS THE PART WHICH THROWS ERROR DURING TRAINING

```
# set training arguments - these params are not really tuned, feel free to change
training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./",
    per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
    predict_with_generate=True,
    #evaluate_during_training=True,
    do_train=True,
    do_eval=True,
    logging_steps=2,  # set to 1000 for full training
    save_steps=16,  # set to 500 for full training
    eval_steps=4,  # set to 8000 for full training
    warmup_steps=1,  # set to 2000 for full training
    max_steps=16, # delete for full training
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    save_total_limit=3,
    fp16=True, 
    #generation_config=None,
)

# instantiate trainer
from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainer
trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=bert2bert,
    args=training_args,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    train_dataset=train_data,
    eval_dataset=val_data,
    
)
trainer.train()
```

here the error is :

> AttributeError: 'Seq2SeqTrainingArguments' object has no attribute 'generation_config'

and i should say that these codes are from the bert2bert notebook .
for using seqtoseqTrainer it used this code :

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huggingface/transformers/master/examples/seq2seq/seq2seq_trainer.py
```

but it did not work at all and apparently the link does not exist so I imported from transformers directly.

my question is how to solve the error I mentioned.
sorry if the question is long.